# How Do I Correct An Incorrectly Flagged Post in Triage?

Tags: support, triage

While reviewing the following question in the Triage queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25854480

I accidentally clicked "requires editing" when I intended to click "unsalvageable". How do I reverse the review?

Comment: I don't think you can change your decision but bringing it up here in Meta or in the [SO Close Vote chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) can get other folks to go in and review it properly. (Be sure to check the rules of the chat room if you go that route.)

Comment: You can always flag by navigating directly to the question (outside of the review queue).